# changing color of the part of label.text

Tags: vb.net

How can i change color of just specific part of the label.text in visual basic 2010 express?

```
Dim b As Integer = 34

label.Text = "You have " & b.ToString & " new items"
```

for example, i just want to change color of the "b" here.

or do i need to create a new label ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is Windows Forms: you need to create a new label.

If it's WPF, you can do it by using a TextBlock with Run elements inside it, and setting the foreground of one of the Run elements.